# Taking multiple images from a folder and perform specific operation in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, entropy

I know how to calculate the entropy of a single image channel. But I want to calculate entropy for each image from a dataset (almost 800), so that the output shows "what percent of images" are in some specific entropy range.

my entropy code: (I'm using MATLAB 2015b)

```
I= im;
Red = I(:,:,1);
Green = I(:,:,2);
Blue = I(:,:,3);

%I = I(:); % Vectorization of RGB values
p = imhist(Red); % Histogram
p(p == 0) = [ ];% remove zero entries in p
p = p ./ numel(I); % normalize p so that sum(p) is one.
Er = round(-sum(p.*log2(p)),3);

p = imhist(Blue); % Histogram
p(p == 0) = [ ];% remove zero entries in p
p = p ./ numel(I); % normalize p so that sum(p) is one.
Eb = round(-sum(p.*log2(p)),3);

figure(1),imshow(im),title(['Entropy for R channel = ', num2str(Er),', Entropy for B channel = ', num2str(Eb)]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your code in a for loop:

```
files = dir('c:\data\*.jpg');  % Or whatever filter will pick your images
for k = 1 : length(files)
   im = fullfile(files(k).folder, files(k).name)
   im = imread(im);
  
   % Your code %
   % but change Er = ... in Er(k) = ... and Eb(k) = ... 
   % so you can store the results
end

percentage = sum(Er > Eb) / numel(Er) * 100; % Percentage of images with red entropy higher than blue entropy

disp(['Percentage of images with red entropy higher than blue entropy: ' num2str(percentage)])
```

Be careful because if you post your code as it is, it will try to open 800 figures!!

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually, I have to find what percent of images has entropy of Red channel higher than Blue channel. In that case, should I use an If-else outside the block? or can you suggest any particular solution?

Comment: @RakibMostafiz I changed the answer with the last bit of information

Comment: Can you please check this? https://pastebin.com/Vpin1N0w    I am getting error. "Undefined function or variable 'Er'.

Error in Untitled (line 25)"

Comment: What's the value of k when you get the error? I am going to guess that the path to the images is wrong, so the variable `files` is empty, and the for look is skipped.

Comment: @RakibMostafiz Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: I have found out that all my images are in .png format. So I changed the extension to .png. but now I am getting another error. I am really sorry to bother you. But I couldn't solve this. Error is "Reference to non-existent field 'folder'" I am using MATLAB 2015b, is this caused the error?

Comment: Please start another question for this problem, with the current code and an example list of the files that are in the folder. It is difficult to help without  enough information...